# The easiest way to write files in vb6?

Tags: file, file-io, vb6

I know how to write files in vb6 but the problem is in my file there are many ( " ) and many lines . I dont want to use vbcrlf to enter or """ to give " result. Is there any easy way to make file in vb6 without using complex things like vbcrlf or _ etc etc.

I want the way in which the data gets entered exactly i type without taking any difficulty for inverted commas or endlines.

Comment: "complex things like vbcrlf"??? Your question makes no sense; there's nothing complex about a carriage return/line feed (which is the Windows end-of-line indicator), and if you don't want line continuation characters (`_`) then don't use them; write the line content directly.

Comment: so just imagine i have 1000 line code do u know that vb6 has a limit to use _ and even we cant write 1000 line without _. So actually my question make sense. I wonder how people write long data in files.

Comment: Then as I said, **write it a single line at at time** instead of trying to write it as a single string. Sorry, but this is not a real question, and my downvote remains.

Comment: Maybe a sample of what you are writing would help as I cannot tell what you want.

Comment: No worries about downvote. I still dont know what i asked wrong but anyways, according to ur reply i guess there is no other way :D

Comment: if you dont want to write out the whole file in 1 line then you can split up the line in separate parts by using a dummy string to which you add the various parts : strDummy = strDummy & strPart1 .... strDummy = strDummy & strPart2 .... strDummy = strDummy & strPart3 .... and_so_on ... that way you can have a part per line of code which makes it easier to read, especially when you group the parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to work with large blocks of literal text it may be easier to create these as separate text files distributed with the program.  Read and use them as needed at runtime.

If you need these embedded within the program you can store them as custom resources, either in Unicode or in ANSI along with appropriate conversion to Unicode after retrieving the data using `LoadResData()` calls.

Avoid `LoadResString()` which is meant for use in localizing application text, another topic altogether.

Most programs don't have a need for so much boilerplate text though.  It can be useful for things like long SQL statements or maybe templates for XML data files.  Simple templates can be processed by inserting `Replace$()` targets ("variables") within them such as `$PATH$` or `$V1$` and such and then inserting your unique information at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

No question exists on this page. Your title, `The easiest way to write files in vb6?` is not a complete sentence. If I try to parse that I would be thinking about file I/O, but there is nothing about that in the body of your message.

In your message, you mention vbcrlf, ", and _. I assume you are having trouble in that some of these characters are recognized by the editor as part of the syntax of VB. " and _ could (possibly?) be difficult to put in code.

Here is a solution (again, if I understand correctly). You can use a function to retrieve a character from the ascii character code. For example, " is ascii code 34. The function Chr() takes the ascii character code and returns a character. If you write something like this:

```
Dim name As String
name = Chr(34) & "Sam" & Chr(34)
```

name will look like "Sam" with the quotes. This overcomes VB recognizing the double quote as syntax.

vbcr is usually Chr(13), which is a carriage return,  followed by a Chr(10), a linefeed

_ is Chr(95)

You can see the full list here:
[asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: i already knew about this and this is more difficult than what i am using currently. what if i need to enter 1000 lines in file having lots and lots of " . So i guess i had to do a drudgery coding for that??